# Show that 2 splitting fields are isomoprhic.

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

Let $f(x) = x^3 + 2x + 1, g(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x + 2$ be polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, let $F$ be a splitting field of $f(x)$ and $E$ be a splitting field of $g(x)$. Since $f, g$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, and their degrees are $3$, degrees of their splitting fields are also $3$.

In my book I have a theorem that says the following (I think it is the one to use): Let $i: K \rightarrow K'$ be a field isomorphism. Let $T$ be a splitting field for $f$ over $K$, $T'$ a splitting field for $i(f)$ over $K'$. Then there is an isomorphism $J: T \rightarrow T'$ such that $j\restriction{K} = i$.

So if I were able to find an isomoprhism $i$ I could tell they are isomorphic. But I don't even know if they are isomoprhic (actually I think they are not).

Comment: That theorem tells us that two splitting fields for the same polynomial are isomorphic: but here we have - on the face of it - splitting fields for two different polynomials. So perhaps you could look at the two splitting fields - what was their order again?- and see if there is any other polynomial which they both split, and then use your theorem.

Comment: The "obvious" tool for this job is to show that the two splitting fields both have 27 elements, and then use uniqueness of finite fields to conclude that they must be isomorphic. There may be a trick with linear substitutions and reciprocal polynomials though. Thinking...

Comment: Define the polynomial $g_1(x):=g(x+1)=x^3+x^2+2$. Then observe that $$-x^3g_1(-1/x)=x^3+2x+1=f(x).$$ So if $\alpha$ is a zero of $g$, then $\alpha-1$ is a zero of $g_1$ and then $1/(1-\alpha)$ is a zero of $f(x)$. So if you adjoin a zero of $g$ you also adjoin a zero of $f$. This should do if you are unwilling to use uniqueness of finite fields.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Do you know any reference for the theorem that helps me to find out the order of splitting field? Because in my book there is not a theorem like that, but I have seen it here in some other questions, so it looks basic.

Comment: The method of Jyrki Lahtonen should help you to conclude that the splitting fields are isomorphic. Adjoining a root of $g$ gives the same field as adjoining a root of $f$.

Comment: If $K$ is a field of order $q$ and $L$ is an extension of $K$ of degree $n$ then $L$ has $q^n$ elements. One sees this by considering $L$ as a vector space over $K$, i.e., $L = \oplus K$ (n copies).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Could you write your comment as an answer? I will mark this as solved then. Thanks for help one more time.